# Multiple ip's for a record (www)

Tags: windows-server-2003

I need to configure DR setup for webserver, if primary isp fails then its needs to be switched on other isp and their ip's. 
Please confirm what step i need to take in this case.

Comment: Dude, have you tried something? Maybe UTFG? Show some effort...

Comment: @Ency this site exists so people don't have to google for answers and go to a bunch of different sites to try and figure out their answer.  People ask questions and they get answered here.

Comment: @August: Of course it is easier to ask instead of try find something first.

Answer (score 2):

1. The simplest system is to keep a low TTL on your DNS entry. If one location fails, manually change the IP to point to your secondary.
2. There are services which will sell you the above service in an automated fashion, and you can buy products from F5 which will handle it for you.
3. At scale, you need BGP. That is far beyond this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with blueben's answer is that while you set just about any TTL you like, in practice a lot of servers will serve stale cache values if it is set very low. There's also a significant amount of manual effort involved and delays between a server going down and notification being available.

The best solution would be to have the site hosted in different locations with a round-robin DNS record - in the event of an outage at one location, the clients will automatically detect the failure, and use the next available address for subsequent addresses. Not exactly transparent as it requires the first request from the client to timeout - but the address will remain sticky on the client for as long as it is cached there.

Distributing a site with anything more complex than static content across locations is not always easy though - but its a very worthwhile goal. In the shorter term, you can do the same thing but keep the server at the standby location down until you know that you need to failover.